# Two Factor ANOVA Errorbar plot in R

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2, anova, confidence-interval

We're teaching a stats class for biology students and trying to use R as the computing and data visualization platform.  As much as possible, we'd like to avoid using extra packages and doing anything terribly "fancy" in R; the focus of the course is on the statistics, not the programming.  Nevertheless, we haven't found a very good way of generating an errorbar plot in R for a two factor ANOVA design.  We're using the ggplot2 package to make the plot, and while it does have a built-in stat_summary method of generating 95% CI errorbars, the way these are calculated may not always be the right way .  Below, I go through the code for the ANOVA by hand and calculate the 95% CIs by hand also (with standard error estimated from the total residual variance, not just the within-group variance ggplot's summary method would use).  At the end, there's actually a plot.

So the question is... is there an easier/faster/simpler way to do all of this?

```
#   LIZARD LENGTH DATA
island.1 <- c(0.2, 5.9, 6.1, 6.5)
island.2 <- c(5.6, 14.8, 15.5, 16.4)
island.3 <- c(0.8, 3.9, 4.3, 4.9)
sex.codes <- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female")

#   PUTTING DATA TOGETHER IN A DATA FRAME
df.1 <- data.frame(island.1, island.2, island.3, sex.codes)

#   MELTING THE DATA FRAME INTO LONG FORM
library(reshape)
df.2 <- melt(df.1)

#   MEAN BY CELL
mean.island1.male <- with(df.2, mean(value[variable == "island.1" & sex.codes == "Male"]))
mean.island1.female <- with(df.2, mean(value[variable == "island.1" & sex.codes == "Female"]))
mean.island2.male <- with(df.2, mean(value[variable == "island.2" & sex.codes == "Male"]))
mean.island2.female <- with(df.2, mean(value[variable == "island.2" & sex.codes == "Female"]))
mean.island3.male <- with(df.2, mean(value[variable == "island.3" & sex.codes == "Male"]))
mean.island3.female <- with(df.2, mean(value[variable == "island.3" & sex.codes == "Female"]))

#   ADDING CELL MEANS TO DATA FRAME
df.2$means[df.2$variable == "island.1" & df.2$sex.codes == "Male"] <- mean.island1.male
df.2$means[df.2$variable == "island.1" & df.2$sex.codes == "Female"] <- mean.island1.female
df.2$means[df.2$variable == "island.2" & df.2$sex.codes == "Male"] <- mean.island2.male
df.2$means[df.2$variable == "island.2" & df.2$sex.codes == "Female"] <- mean.island2.female
df.2$means[df.2$variable == "island.3" & df.2$sex.codes == "Male"] <- mean.island3.male
df.2$means[df.2$variable == "island.3" & df.2$sex.codes == "Female"] <- mean.island3.female

#   LINEAR MODEL
lizard.model <- lm(value ~ variable*sex.codes, data=df.2)

#   CALCULATING RESIDUALS BY HAND:
df.2$residuals.1 <- df.2$value - df.2$means

#   CONFIRMING RESIDUALS FROM LINEAR MODEL:
df.2$residuals.2 <- residuals(lizard.model)

#   TWO FACTOR MAIN EFFECT ANOVA
lizard.anova <- anova(lizard.model)        

#   INTERACTION PLOT
interaction.plot(df.2$variable, df.2$sex.codes, df.2$value)

#   SAMPLE SIZE IN EACH CELL
n <- length(df.2$value[df.2$variable == "island.1" & df.2$sex.codes == "Male"])
# > n
# [1] 2

#   NOTE: JUST FOR CLARITY, PRETEND n=10
n <- 10

#   CALCULATING STANDARD ERROR
island.se <- sqrt(lizard.anova$M[4]/n)

#   HALF CONFIDENCE INTERVAL
island.ci.half <- qt(0.95, lizard.anova$D[4]) * island.se

#   MAKING SUMMARY DATA FRAME
summary.df <- data.frame(
        Means = c(mean.island1.male,
                mean.island1.female,
                mean.island2.male,
                mean.island2.female,
                mean.island3.male,
                mean.island3.female),
        Location = c("island1",
                "island1",
                "island2",
                "island2",
                "island3",
                "island3"),
        Sex = c("male",
                "female",
                "male",
                "female",
                "male",
                "female"),      
        CI.half = rep(island.ci.half, 6)        
        )

# > summary.df
# Means Location    Sex  CI.half
# 1  3.15  island1   male 2.165215
# 2  6.20  island1 female 2.165215
# 3 10.55  island2   male 2.165215
# 4 15.60  island2 female 2.165215
# 5  2.55  island3   male 2.165215
# 6  4.40  island3 female 2.165215

#   GENERATING THE ERRORBAR PLOT
library(ggplot2)

qplot(data=summary.df,
        y=Means,
        x=Location,
        group=Sex,
        ymin=Means-CI.half,
        ymax=Means+CI.half,
        geom=c("point", "errorbar", "line"),
        color=Sex,
        shape=Sex,
        width=0.25) + theme_bw()
```

[image: ggplot2 errobar plot of Two-way Main Effects Anova]

Comment: In the code above, I went through calculating the various treatment means by hand, but obviously that's not necessary; it's just something we want the students doing to get a feel for the calculations.  For making the errorbar plot, all we really need from the ANOVA is the Error Mean Square, which R calculates quite fast, and which is used in the 95% CI calculation.  Still, to make the figure seems to require making that extra "summary.df" summary data frame.

Comment: I got the message: you don't want to use fancy packages. Still though I have to say: You are using Hadley Wickham's package to plot why not arrange your data (particularly mean by cell etc) the Hadley way: at least have a look at `reshape` and `plyr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another attempt using the sciplot package. Alternative ways to compute the confidence intervals can be passed in parameter ci.fun.

```
lineplot.CI(variable,value, group =sex.codes , data = df.2, cex = 1.5,
            xlab = "Location", ylab = "means", cex.lab = 1.2, x.leg = 1,
            col = c("blue","red"), pch = c(16,16))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have to admit I'm quite baffled by your code. Don't take this as personal criticism, but I strongly advise you to learn your students to use the power of R as much as possible. They can only benefit from it, and my experience is that they understand faster what's going on if I don't throw lines and lines of code clutter to their heads.

First of all, you don't have to calculate the means by hand. Just do:

```
df.2$mean <- with(df.2,ave(value,sex.codes,variable,FUN=mean))
```

See also `?ave`. That is more clear than the clutter of code in your example. If you have the lizard.model, you can just use

```
fitted(lizard.model)
```

and compare these values to the means.

Then I strongly disagree with you. What you calculate, is not the standard error on your prediction. To do that correctly, use the `predict()` function

```
outcome <- predict(lizard.model,se.fit=TRUE)
df.2$CI.half <- outcome$se / 2
```

To get the confidence interval on the predicted means, you have to use the correct formulae if you ever want your students to understand this correctly. Take a look at section 3.5 of this incredibly great [Practical Regression and Anova using R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf) from Faraway. It contains tons of code examples where everything is calculated by hand in a convenient and concise way. It will serve both you and your students. I learnt a lot from it and use it often as a guideline when explaining these things to students.

Now to get the summary dataframe you have a few options, but this one works and is quite understandible.

```
summary.df <- unique(df.2[,-c(3,5,6)])
names(summary.df) <- c('Sex','Location','Means','CI.half')
```

And now you can just run your plot code as it stands there.

Alternatively, if you want the prediction error on your values, you can use the following:

```
lizard.predict <- predict(lizard.model,interval='prediction')
df.2$lower <- lizard.predict[,2]
df.2$upper <- lizard.predict[,3]

summary.df <- unique(df.2[,-3])
names(summary.df)[1:3] <- c('Sex','Location','Means')


qplot(data=summary.df,
        y=Means,
        x=Location,
        group=Sex,
        ymin=lower,
        ymax=upper,
        geom=c("point", "errorbar", "line"),
        color=Sex,
        shape=Sex,
        width=0.25) + theme_bw()
```

PS: If I sound harsh here and there, that's not intended. English is not my mothertongue, and I'm still not acquainted with the subtleties of the language.

Answer (score 4):

[Potential shameless promotion] You should consider the functions compareCats and rxnNorm in package HandyStuff, available at [www.github.com/bryanhanson/HandyStuff](http://github.com/bryanhanson/HandyStuff)  Warning: I'm not sure it works seamlessly with R 2.14.  In particular, rxnNorm looks like the plot you are trying to produce, plus it gives you a variety of options in terms of the summarizing stats and decorations to the plot.  But, this requires having your students install a separate package, so perhaps you will rule it out (but it allows students to concentrate on the presenting and analyzing the data).  Plot from the ?rxnNorm example included here.[image]

With rxnNorm you have a choice of several ways of calculating the CI's, controlled by argument "method".  Here are the actual functions (from package ChemoSpec).

```
> seX <- function (x)  sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(length(na.omit(x)))
> <environment: namespace:ChemoSpec>
> 
> seXy <- function (x)  {
>     m <- mean(na.omit(x))
>     se <- seX(x)
>     u <- m + se
>     l <- m - se
>     c(y = m, ymin = l, ymax = u) } <environment: namespace:ChemoSpec>
> 
> 
> seXy95 <- function (x)  {
>     m <- mean(na.omit(x))
>     se <- seX(x)
>     u <- m + 1.96 * se
>     l <- m - 1.96 * se
>     c(y = m, ymin = l, ymax = u) } <environment: namespace:ChemoSpec>
> 
> 
> seXyIqr <- function (x)  {
>     i <- fivenum(x)
>     c(y = i[3], ymin = i[2], ymax = i[4]) } <environment: namespace:ChemoSpec>
> 
> seXyMad <- function (x)  {
>     m <- median(na.omit(x))
>     d <- mad(na.omit(x))
>     u <- m + d
>     l <- m - d
>     c(y = m, ymin = l, ymax = u) } <environment: namespace:ChemoSpec>
```

Comment: How are the CIs calculated in this package?

Comment: You have a choice of several CI methods, handled by a set of functions in the ChemoSpec package.  They don't fit in the comment space, I'll append to my earlier answer.