# Connecting means in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build some kind of profile diagram with ggplot2. I therefore want a line which connects the means in the plot. As you see, `geom_line` doesn't work here because it only connects the points within each factor level but not the means between factor levels.

Here's a small example:

```
df <- data.frame(variable=rep(1:3,each=10),value=rnorm(30))
p <- ggplot(df,aes(factor(variable),value))
p + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point")+coord_flip()+geom_line()
```

Does anyone has an idea how to achieve that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect mean points of error bars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504721/connect-mean-points-of-error-bars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often easier to summarize the data before you plot. Something like

The next trick is to use `group` within the call to `geom_line` to override the default grouping by `factor(variable)`

```
summarydf <- ddply(df,.(variable),summarize, value = mean(value))
p <- ggplot(summarydf,aes(factor(variable),value))  + 
  geom_point() + geom_line(aes(group=1)) + coord_flip()
p
```

[image]